# Solving a trigonometric equation for the angle in radian

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I have been trying to solve the following equation in radians:

```
NSolve[0.6` Cos[π/6 + 2.` x ] + Sin[x] == 0, x]
```

Following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219072/54258), I can modify the code as

```
NSolve[0.6` Cos[π/6 + 2.` x ] + Sin[x] == 0 && -4*Pi < x < 4*Pi, x]
```

but I am getting solutions as

```
{{x -> -9.14254}, {x -> -6.82007}, {x -> -2.85935}, {x -> -0.536885},
 {x -> 3.42384}, {x -> 5.7463}, {x -> 9.70702}, {x -> 12.0295}}
```

Is there any way to get the solution directly in radians (e.g. in the form `π/6`)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Exact solutions require the use of exact numbers and exact solvers

```
eqn = 0.6` Cos[π/6 + 2.` x] + Sin[x] == 0 // Rationalize

(* 3/5 Cos[π/6 + 2 x] + Sin[x] == 0 *)

FunctionPeriod[eqn[[1]], x]

(* 2 π *)
```

Since the expression has a period of 2 Pi, it is only necessary to look at an interval of 2 Pi

```
sol = SolveValues[{eqn, -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x]
```

[image]

The exact solution is in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions. Use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to convert to algebraic form

```
sol2 = sol // ToRadicals

(* {-2 ArcTan[√(337/27 + 
      1/27 √(2 (55628 - 91134 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) + 
            9 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(1/3))) + 
      1/2 √(890048/729 + 
          81008/81 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) - 
          8/81 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(1/3) + 
          148555552/
           729 √(2/(55628 - 
                91134 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) + 
                9 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(
                 1/3)))))], -2 ArcTan[√(337/27 + 
      1/27 √(2 (55628 - 91134 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) + 
            9 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(1/3))) - 
      1/2 √(890048/729 + 
          81008/81 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) - 
          8/81 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(1/3) + 
          148555552/
           729 √(2/(55628 - 
                91134 (2/(-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301]))^(1/3) + 
                9 2^(2/3) (-180781 + 1107 Sqrt[450301])^(1/3)))))]} *)
```

To get an approximate result

```
approx = Round[sol, Pi/2^10]

(* {-((233 π)/256), -((175 π)/1024)} *)
```

The relative error is

```
(sol - approx)/sol // N

(* {3.48902*10^-6, -0.0000163307} *)
```